# if/else loop with (almost) daily events

Tags: entries, datetime, forloop

Building further on [this problem](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/targeting-entries-in-a-structure), I try to make a loop that exits when the next opening hours or in other case events are found.

There is an event on all days except monday. I added a couple of extra elseif statements in case they drop a couple of events.

I have the following code (based on the answer below I changed my code)

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').level(2) %}
  {% if entry.dayOfEvent == now|date("l") %}
    {{ entry.dayOfEvent }}
  {% elseif entry.dayOfEvent == now|date_modify("+1 day")|date("l") %}
    {{ entry.dayOfEvent }}
  {% elseif entry.dayOfEvent == now|date_modify("+2 days")|date("l") %}
    {{ entry.dayOfEvent }}
  {% elseif entry.dayOfEvent == now|date_modify("+3 days")|date("l") %}
    {{ entry.dayOfEvent }}
  {% else %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't seem to do it. It's probably basic stuff, but what am i doing wrong?

**Update**

*Based on the answer below I changed my code*

The output clearly gives me my days. But the {% elseif %} doesn't work, I just get the day outputted as well for all events in that range. Shouldn't it exit the loop as soon as the condition is met?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because `entry.dayOfEvent` isn't returning exactly what `"now"|date_modify('+1 day')` is returning therefore the comparison fails.  Maybe one includes the time and the other doesn't, for example.

You can see what each is returning by doing:

```
{{ entry.dayOfEvent }}
{{ "now"|date_modify('+1 day') }}
```

If they are different formats, then you can make the 2nd one match the format of the first by using [Twig's date format method](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#date).

Comment: thx for your input.. I updated the question in hope for further help.

Comment: What are the possible values for `entry.dayOfEvent`?

Comment: I tried with day names and with the numbers 1-7 with the |date("N") format. The results are fine. If it's wednesday it show that day. If i switch it to numbers it show the number and the entries. It may work with [this plugin](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue) i'm currently testing. But i get deleted entries returned. ex i created an event wednesday test that I deleted from the structure, but it still comes up in the results. It looks like the entry is still in the dB.